# ¿Como puedo Habilitar un "select option" con un boton en JS

Tags: javascript, html

basicamente es aprender como puedo hacer eso, he visto muchos ejemplos de como se hace pero siempre es de un slect a otro o viceversa a lo que requiero, espero me puedan ayudar.

estos son mi `select`

```
    <select class="form-control" name="tipoPre" id="tipoPre" disable>
<option value="0" >Seleccione una opcion</option>
<option value="1">Pregunta Abierta Larga</option>
<option value="2">Pregunta Abierta Corta</option>
<option value="3">Opción Múltiple</option>
<option value="4">Opción Única</option>
<option value="5">Valoración</option>
<option value="6">Opción Múltiple con Respuesta Abierta</option>
<option value="7">Opción Única con Respuesta Abierta</option>
    </select>
```

Y este es mi Boton

```
<input type="button" id="ok_nombre_encuesta" name="ok_nombre_encuesta" class="btn btn-primary ok_nombre" value="OK" />
```

Basimante es que cuando den click en el boton, se habilite la parte del Select

---

Revisando Edito para dar una solucion mas correcta

Basicamente este es mi boton

```
<td class="table">
<label for="">Nombre de la encuesta</label>
<input type="text" id="nameenc" class="form-control col-sm-6" name="descripcion_a" id="descripcion_a" placeholder="Nombre o descripcion de la encuesta...">
    </td>

td class="table">
    <br>
<input type="button" id="ok_nombre_encuesta" name="ok_nombre_encuesta" class="btn btn-primary ok_nombre" value="OK" onclick="enable()" />
    </td>
```

y el JS quedo asi (agrege una pequeña validacion

```
<script type="text/javascript">//script para enable or disable del Option
            function disable() {
                  document.getElementById("tipoPre").disabled=true;
                }
                function enable() {


                    //var campo = $('#ok_nombre_encuesta').val();
                    if ($('#nameenc').val() === '') {
                     alert('El campo "Nombre de la Encuesta", no puede estar vacio');
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     document.getElementById("tipoPre").disabled=false;
                    }
                }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo necesitas cambiar el valor de la propiedad `disabled` a `false` asi:

```js
function habilitar() {
  var e = document.getElementById("tipoPre");
  e.options[e.selectedIndex].disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="tipoPre" id="tipoPre">
<option value="0" disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion</option>
<option value="1">Pregunta Abierta Larga</option>
<option value="2">Pregunta Abierta Corta</option>
<option value="3">Opción Múltiple</option>
<option value="4">Opción Única</option>
<option value="5">Valoración</option>
<option value="6">Opción Múltiple con Respuesta Abierta</option>
<option value="7">Opción Única con Respuesta Abierta</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="ok_nombre_encuesta" name="ok_nombre_encuesta" class="btn btn-primary ok_nombre" value="OK" onClick="habilitar()"/>
```

Comment: mmm.. no me llega a funcionar, lo deja desabilitado

Comment: Como puedes ver aqui si funciona.

Comment: si, perdon fue error mio, el boton lo estaba tomando como el "input" pero en realidad era otro, ya solo modifique los id y listo ya quedo